# Select A Button By Class jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to have a button that, when clicked, will have some jQuery code linked to it. See the general layout below. However, there will be a variable number of rows on the table. All the buttons should have the same action but applied to its parent  element. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Info</td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Info</td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Info</td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See [jQuery's `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below does what you need, it will check any click within a `table` element to see if it matches the required pattern (in this case a `button` with class `.remove`), before then actioning the code.

I've added a dynamically added row so you can test it.

If you aren't having dynamically added rows (i.e. they are all there before this code is run) then you can simply use:

```
$("table button.remove").click( function() {

    $(this).closest("tr").remove();

});
```

---

```js
// Add click event linked to the table
// Will trigger whenever a button with class .remove is clicked within the table
$( "table" ).on( "click", "button.remove", function() {

  // Move up DOM tree to nearest 'tr' and remove it
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();

});


// Add click event to add row button
$("#add-row").click( function() {

  // Add dynamic row for testing
  $("table").append('<tr><td>Info</td><td><button class="remove">Remove row</button></td></tr>');

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Info</td>
    <td><button class="remove">Remove row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="add-row">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in several ways, question is tagged with jQuery so the easiest way using jQuery is :

```
$("button").on("click", function(ev) {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove()
});
```

This will remove `tr` element when clicked on it's button, you can do what you want inside that anonymous function

Comment: he want to select a btn with remove class

Comment: I'm not his employee and I'm not going to code for him, that was an example and he could easily replace the selector!

Comment: amazing bro , you're right 

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let btns = $("button.remove"); // you will select only buttons with remove class
```

in your case you want something like this :

```
btns.each(function(){
let btn  = $(this);
   btn.on('click',()=>{
    // your stuff
   })
})
```

i hope it was useful !